# Set the visibility of wpf CheckBox to hidden if its value is false

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am populating a datagrid using Binding property. For each row a checkbox also appears. However, I want to hide checkboxes for certain rows although the row is not empty. If the property that is used to bind the checkbox is set to false, the checkbox should be hidden. Is this possible?

I have defined a class with the instance variables that are used to bind the DataGridTextColumn and Checkbox, as follows:

```
    public class DataSet
    {
        public string XDim { get; set; }
        public string YDim { get; set; }
        public bool Selected { get; set; }
    }
```

The Datagrid is defined as follows:

```
 <DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=XDim }" Width="65" Header="X Dimension" IsReadOnly="True"/>

         <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=YDim}" Width="85" Header="Y Dimension" IsReadOnly="True"/>

         <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Selected}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                        <CheckBox Margin="20,3,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay,
                                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}"/>
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

What I tried is create a boolean property `visibility` (`public bool visibility{ get; set;}`) and the checkbox is Hidden if `visibility` is set to false. But nothing happens. What am I missing? I created a style as follows and applied this to the checkbox:

```
<Style x:Key="cBVisibility" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=visibility,Path=Text}" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Selected}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ToggleButton Margin="0" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ToggleButton.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                                <Grid Background="Transparent">
                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ToggleButton.Template>
                        <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource cBVisibility}" Margin="20,3,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ToggleButton}}" Visibility="{Binding visibility}" />
                    </ToggleButton>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: There could be a Trigger in the ControlTemplate. Why is there a CheckBox in the Content of a ToggleButton? That doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Since wanted to have single click CheckBox, it is in the Content of a ToggleButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't follow why you put your style in a resource separate from the checkbox.  I would lose the togglebutton.

I suggest you try:

```
    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Selected" ClipboardContentBinding="{Binding Selected}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <CheckBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="CheckBox">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Selected}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style>
                        </Style>
                    </CheckBox.Style>
                </CheckBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You should also implement inotifypropertychanged on all viewmodels.
DataSet is a viewmodel.
Since DataSet is already a class in System.Data, that does not seem an ideal name for a viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the changes to your DataSet class to be detected by the DataGrid you need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in DataSet so that the PropertyChanged event fires when the property is changed.